# How can I add 20px margin only to divs on the left hand side (flex)

Tags: html, css

The divs are using flex & flex-wrap, and I only want to apply margin-right to the divs on the left hand side as when clicked the border is pushed up against the divs on the right hand side. Any ideas how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: you can use something like `div:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}` to target even elements (or use odd to target odd elements, whatever suits your needs best)

Comment: Thanks @cloned that will work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
div:nth-child(even){ 
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Posting your code would help a lot.